# How to define flip animation

Tags: android, animation

I want to make flip like animation of my ImageView after I click on that. My intent is to shrink width of an image to 0 and immediately after that expand it back to 1.0. This should simulate flip of the image.

This is what I actually have. After click on the image it shrink image from 1.0 to 0.

My question is how to continue with expanding part of animation?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <scale
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
            android:fromXScale="1.0"
            android:toXScale="0.0"
            android:fromYScale="1.0"
            android:toYScale="1.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="200" />
 </set>
```

**EDIT**

I added another block for reverse part of animation but it does not work as expected. It seem that startOffset is not taken in effect or something like that. In other words animation is messed-up it seems that also first part of animation is affected by this additional code. What I am doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <scale
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
            android:fromXScale="1.0"
            android:toXScale="0.0"
            android:fromYScale="1.0"
            android:toYScale="1.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="200" />
    <set android:startOffset="200">
        <scale
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
            android:fromXScale="0.0"
            android:toXScale="1.0"
            android:fromYScale="1.0"
            android:toYScale="1.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="200" />
    </set>
 </set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After next R&D I found that this piece of code exactly do what I want it to do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

    <scale
            android:fromXScale="1.0"
            android:toXScale="0.0"
            android:fromYScale="1.0"
            android:toYScale="1.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="200"
            android:repeatCount="2"
            android:repeatMode="reverse"/>

    </set>
```

It means that I added `repeatMode` and `repeatCount` to animation definition ant this works as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Bury another `<set> <scale /> </set>` inside your first set, but after the initial scale.  This will make them fire sequentially.

See this page for an example.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Comment: I added second part (please refer to original post EDIT part) of animation but it does not work as expected. I am expecting that after first part of animation is done (first scale) then second parts will start. But it does not so. Entire animation is weird and it seems that also first part is affected by this additional code. I expect that first scale will work as it was. Meanwhile second part waits for 200milis and then will start.